# Insert a new key value to the existing object array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

My object looks like this:

[image: object]

I want to add the key value that contains the arrays as a value in the object to achieve something like this:

```
{avg: 16, day: "2020-12-11", max: 25, min: 8,value:"o3"}
{avg: 18, day: "2020-12-12", max: 21, min: 15,value:"o3"}
{avg: 10, day: "2020-12-13", max: 16, min: 6,value:"o3"}
{avg: 16, day: "2020-12-11", max: 19, min: 12, value: "pm10"}
{avg: 11, day: "2020-12-12", max: 17, min: 6, value: "pm10"}
{avg: 20, day: "2020-12-13", max: 26, min: 10, poluant: "pm10"}
```

I tried to loop through each object and to add the value at the end  like this and works but i wonder if i can do this without to loop through each object(in the end i have five for loops):

```
for (let item of this.o3) {
    item.value = 'o3';
}
    
for (let item of this.pm10) {
    item.value = 'pm10';
}
```

Comment: The image is not JSON. Please read the usage description of the `json` tag, especially the "do not use" part.

Comment: Objects don't have "order", so there is not an beginning or end.

Comment: i know is not a json,my json  conatins more data and i just posted the lines that i want to change

Comment: If you know it is not JSON, then why do you call it JSON? (I removed the references to this term).

Comment: I think what'd be helpful so we can best help you troubleshoot this is providing an exact input and output example

Comment: Without showing viable code there is no proper way to provide assistance.

Comment: i edit my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jou can do it by using loop inside a loop

```js
var daily = {
o3 : [{avg: 16, day: "2020-12-11", max: 25, min: 8},
{avg: 18, day: "2020-12-12", max: 21, min: 15},
{avg: 10, day: "2020-12-13", max: 16, min: 6},
{avg: 16, day: "2020-12-11", max: 19, min: 12},
{avg: 11, day: "2020-12-12", max: 17, min: 6},
{avg: 20, day: "2020-12-13", max: 26, min: 10}
],
pm10 : [{avg: 16, day: "2020-12-11", max: 25, min: 8},
{avg: 18, day: "2020-12-12", max: 21, min: 15},
{avg: 10, day: "2020-12-13", max: 16, min: 6},
{avg: 16, day: "2020-12-11", max: 19, min: 12},
{avg: 11, day: "2020-12-12", max: 17, min: 6},
{avg: 20, day: "2020-12-13", max: 26, min: 10 }
]} ;


for(item in daily){
  
  
 if(item == "o3"){
   daily[item] = daily[item].map(x=> x = { ...x, value:"o3"} )
 }else if("pm10"){
   daily[item] = daily[item].map(x=> x = { ...x, value:"pm10"} )
}
  
}

console.log(daily)
```